# XSLT to map elements copied file

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I would like to copy an entire file, manipulate some of its elements by mapping it to corresponding elements in the original xml xsl file. Assume I have a table that tells me which elements from file2 ought to be mapped to corresponding elements in file2. As an example, element writer from file2 ought to be mapped to element author in file1.
For the sake of brevity, let say file1 looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Books>
      <book1>
        <title>Things fall apart</title>
        <author name = "Chinua Achebe" nationality = "Nigerian" />
      </book1>
    </Books>
```

And file2 looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Books>
      <book2>
        <title> 1984</title>
        <writer>George Orwel</writer>
      </book2>
    </Books>
```

And I have the following XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>  

    <xsl:template match="Books">
      <Bundle>
        <id value="test"/>
        <resource>
          <!-- I am copying into here the entire File2 -->    
          <xsl:copy-of select="document('file2.xml')/*"/>      
        </resource>             
      </Bundle>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
```

Now, I know that element writer in file2 which I copied in its entirety needs to be mapped to its corresponding element in file1, namely author, so that in the end whenever element writer occurs in file2, it is changed to thus:

```
<author name = "Chinua Achebe" nationality = "Nigerian" />
```

And this should be the final output.

```
<Bundle>
    <id value="test"/>
    <resource>
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!-- Here, the copied and modified file2-->  
        <Books>
            <book2>
                    <title> 1984</title>
                    <author name = "Chinua Achebe" nationality = "Nigerian" />
            </book2>
        </Books>

</resource>             
  </Bundle>
```

Comment: Could you post the (entire) expected output of the transformation?

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness: I fixed your `author` tag in `file1.xml`.

Comment: Hmm. `file1.xml` and `file2.xml` do not both have a `<writer>` tag, so your question is kind of quirky. In `file1` you call it `author` and in `file2` you call it `writer`. How do you like to handle that discrepancy?

Comment: @zx485 Thanks for the fix. Only file2.xml has a writer tag but I want to map the author element in file1.xml into the writer element in file2.xml by renaming it into writer and then copying every other thing that it may have like attributes etc. such that final output looks like:

`<Books>
  <book1>
    <title> Things fall apart</title>
    <writer>Chinua Achebe</writer>
  <book1>`

Comment: @Enigma **1.** Please don't post code in comments - edit your question instead. **2.** Please clarify: this output does not match what you show in your question. It doesn't contain anything from file2, except the name of the `writer` element. How would the stylesheet know which element "corresponds" to `author` in file1?

Comment: Sorry, will edit the question next time if code needs changing. 

Basically, this is desired:
First, I copied the entire file2. Now, there are some elements that correspond to elements in file1. These elements are known to me. E.g. the element author. Now, this element will be renamed to its correspondent element in file2, i.e. renamed into writer as you can see in the example. After renaming, the entire content of this element (everything like attributes and so on) as they are in file1 should replace its correspondent element in file2 and this should be outputed, not the original copied file2

Comment: I am afraid this is still very confusing. If you know that `writer` should be renamed to `author` then make your stylesheet do that explicitly (and don't use `xsl:copy`). I don't see how one could use file1 to make such renaming dynamic, unless the structures are exactly identical and the **only** difference is the element names.

Comment: Hi, michael.hor257k, first, thanks a lot for your patience and your persistence in wanting to help me. It is much appreciated. 

But how can I make the styelsheet do that explicitly when it is not the standard file (i.e. it is not the file that the xslt processes by default), rather it is copied external file? This other file is an external file that I have imported (or copied as you can see in the xsl data) using the xslt stylesheet. Yes, file1 as the standard input xml file, I can manipulate it explicitly using the styelsheet but the copied external file2? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: I have a java program that takes as input 2 xml files (the xml file to be manipulated, in this case, file1 and the xslt xml file that says how and what to manipulate) and output the resulting xml file. So, I don't know how I can then explicitly manipulate file2, which is not taken as an input. That is why I was thinking of copy file2 into the xslt and then manipulate it. Or maybe XSLT can process several files simultaneously as if they are one, or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you can't use `file2.xml` as the source XML for the transformation - or why you even need the `file1.xml` here.

In any case, you can easily apply templates to nodes in another document  (or use `xsl:for-each` on them). Here's an example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <Bundle>
        <id value="test"/>
        <resource>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="document('file2.xml')/*"/> 
        </resource>          
    </Bundle>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="writer">
    <author>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </author>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this transformation is applied to **any** well-formed XML source (note that your `file1.xml` is **not** well-formed), the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Bundle>
   <id value="test"/>
   <resource>
      <Books>
         <book2>
            <title> 1984</title>
            <author>George Orwel</author>
         </book2>
      </Books>
   </resource>
</Bundle>
```

Note that this is not the result shown in your question. As I already mentioned in comments to your question, If you want to use the entire `author` node from `file1.xml` as a replacement for the `writer` node in `file2.xml`, you will need to provide the logic by which the stylesheet can identify which property of which book to use as the replacement.

For example, if both files have only one `Book`, you could use:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="input" select="/" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <Bundle>
        <id value="test"/>
        <resource>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="document('file2.xml')/*"/> 
        </resource>          
    </Bundle>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="writer">
    <xsl:copy-of select="$input/Books/book1/author"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Given a **well-formed** input such as:

**XML**

```
<Books>
    <book1>
        <title>Things fall apart</title>
        <author name = "Chinua Achebe" nationality = "Nigerian"></author>
    </book1>
</Books>
```

this would return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Bundle>
   <id value="test"/>
   <resource>
      <Books>
         <book2>
            <title> 1984</title>
            <author name="Chinua Achebe" nationality="Nigerian"/>
         </book2>
      </Books>
   </resource>
</Bundle>
```

Comment: I am using file1 as the source since it is the main document for which I have to do the transformation from. But there may also be other files, like file2, file3 etc. that are related that I need to manipulate in order to get one output.  I sort of like your idea. If I understand it correctly, you are defining a variable for file1, which is the source file. Then with apply-template, you are loading file2. And from there, you can use file2 as if it were source by applying the xsl stylesheet explicitly, just as if it were source xml and I can manipulate it then as desired?

Comment: Thanks. That seems to have done the trick. Sort of. With `<xsl:copy-of select="$input/Books/book1/author"/>` I can copy the entire author node but what if I want to retain the name writer for author so that I get `<writer name="Chinua Achebe" nationality="Nigerian"/>`. I can see 2 options: one is to copy only the child nodes of author (only attributes in this case) and not the node itself but it seems I can't do something like `<xsl:copy-of select="$input/Books/book1/author/node()"/>`. Another is to change author in source to writer and then copy but xslt doesn't process by order AFAIK.

Comment: If you want to further process the nodes, use `xsl:apply-templates` instead of `xsl:copy-of` and add templates to match the nodes you want to modify.

Answer (score 0):

Why not put the content of `file2.xml` into a variable?

Example (not related to the particular files you posted):

```
<xsl:variable name="params">
    <xsl:copy-of select="doc('xslt_params.xml')"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

Then you can access anything from the entire document. Example:

```
<xsl:variable name="lang">
    <xsl:value-of select="$params/descendant::param[1]/@lang1"/>
</xsl:variable>
```